# Symfony form inside a form, parent form sumbit button not working

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms, symfony5

I have a form and inside this one I added another form.
The second form is working good but the second is not working.

There is the form part in my Twig template

```
<div>
{{ form_start(registrationForm) }}
    <div>
        {{ form_label(registrationForm.name, 'name') }}
        {{ form_widget(registrationForm.name) }}
    </div>
    <div>
        ...
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            <a>Change password</a>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div>
                {{ form_start(passwordForm) }}
                    {{ form_label(passwordForm.password, 'change password') }}
                    {{ form_widget(passwordForm.password) }}
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit">Save</button>
                    </div>
                {{ form_end(passwordForm) }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ form_label(registrationForm.email, 'email') }}
        {{ form_widget(registrationForm.email) }}
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
{{ form_end(registrationForm) }}
```

So the `passwordForm` is working (the button submits it) but the `registration form` submit button doesn't work anymore. Does anyone have an idea about how to resolve this issue? Thanks!

EDIT:
Fixed this issue by taking out the `passwordForm` and putting it **after** the `registerationForm`. In my case, the position doesn't matter because it's a modal which appears when the button is clicked.

Comment: This is not a good/correct way to add a form inside a form. Check [embedded forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/embedded.html)

Comment: I don't follow the logic, why would you change password before you are actually registered? what is this form trying to achieve? As above you can embed forms properly but that doesn't seem like what you want here, I really don't know what it is you do want though.

Comment: Yup I know but I have no other choice. My form is ment to be a user update form but the person who updates it isn't allowed to see the password so I remove the password field in the controller and I add the other window after. What shoud I do to replace that ?

Comment: @JasonStephenson the `registerationForm` is not really clear I agree with you. Look my precedent comment to see what I want to do.

Comment: Maybe if you add SubmitType in each of your forms instead of manually putting a submit button it might work. Also make sure the forms have different actions.

Comment: @EnzoKilm ok I understand now, it's like an admin changing the users email/password - why not just make a new form? You need to add a password field but set it as mapped = false - this means that it will not be related to any database field, you then need to read this value in your controller and handle the encryption and update that value (not the plaintext value). Since you will set mapped to false the password will not be auto-filled. https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#mapped